# what is the exact difference between intent and pending intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Pending Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-pending-intent)

I'm confused about ***intent*** and ***pending intent***.
Can anyone explain what exactly is the difference between both? I've searched on SO, I found this link but **it didn't meet with my need**: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633810/what-is-difference-between-an-intent-and-a-pending-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633810/what-is-difference-between-an-intent-and-a-pending-inten).

i know Pending intent is an intent which will start later on. Normal intent is started at the time it is passed to `startActivity(intent)` or `StartService(intent)`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-pending-intent/4812421#4812421

Comment: http://android-pending-intent.blogspot.in/     may be help you.