# what is pending intent and use of it a android

Tags: android

Can someone please help me understand  "*pending intent*"? Some examples would really help too.

I have googled for it and found some information, but I am still having trouble understanding it.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

Updater() {
  notificationManager = (NotificationManager) UpdaterService.this
      .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notification = new Notification( android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download,
      "MyTwitter", System.currentTimeMillis());
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(UpdaterService.this, 0,
      new Intent(UpdaterService.this, Timeline.class), 0);
}
```

Comment: Please define : `frnd, qus, explian, pls`, i am not understood it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Pending Intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-pending-intent)

Comment: @gens no need  of you to understand..he he he

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pending intent, is like describing an Intent for later use. It's kind of, in real sense like having a recipe to make that same intent up again.

For the AlarmManager, it means it can just store the PendingIntent somewhere else and just make the Intent when needed. Also it means the Intent can be easily repeated.

(As far as I know anyway, anyone correct me if i'm wrong)