# can anybody explain the pending intent and its parameters

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am a beginner to android programming can anybody explain me about the pending intents and its uses,please explain the parameters of pending intents   also

thanx in advance!!

Comment: You can find details here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: This question have already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-pending-intent Hope it helps. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pending Intent is an Intent that can be executed at a later time. They are just like regular intents except they can have some extra properties that allow them to stay alive so that they can be executed by other apps even after the originating process is killed.

Here are some resources to learn more:

- [Official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)
- [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html#pendingintent)
- [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-pending-intent)