# Are PendingIntents created by createPendingResult(int, android.content.Intent, int) secure?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Are PendingIntents created by [createPendingResult(int, android.content.Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#createPendingResult(int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) secure against Intent spoofing attacks?

Looking into the source code of the [Activity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.createPendingResult%28int%2Candroid.content.Intent%2Cint%29) class, I see that there is a getPackage(). However, it is not clear to me whether the resulting PendingIntent is restricted only to the app into whose context it was created.

Comment: Not exactly sure what kind of Intent-spoofing you are concerned about. Can you give me an example of Intent-spoofing that could (theoretically) be done with a `PendingIntent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not safe.**

Frist of all, check this questions to get more details about PendingIntent, and why it's not safe:[What is an Android PendingIntent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808796/what-is-an-android-pendingintent)

Secondly, **one very important thing**, which the above question's all answers not mentioned, is that the intent inside the PendingIntent could be changed after the PendingIntent being created! Which means, **the behavior of the PendingIntent could be changed when you give it to another application.** This is controled by the `flags` paremeter. check for   [createPendingResult (int requestCode, Intent data, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#createPendingResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and [Intent.fillIn (Intent other, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#fillIn%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for more details.
And CVE-2014-8609 is a very good example, google it.

Finally, from the source code of the [Activity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.createPendingResult%28int%2Candroid.content.Intent%2Cint%29) class and the [PendingIntent](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/PendingIntent.java#283) class, we can see the implemention of 
`createPendingResult` and `PendingIntent.getActivity` is very similar, means the returned PendingIntent have same risk.